# Displaying multiple dynamic posts using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am new to asp.net (web forms) and want to get some information from database and then display this information in the form of posts , like heading , paragraph and an image. If there are three rows in database there would be three posts. I have done this using asp.net code in .aspx file

```
 <% 
     while (reader.Read())
     { %>
      <article class="col1">
           <h2><%= reader.GetValue(0).ToString()%></h2>

           <p class="pad_bot1"><%= reader.GetValue(1).ToString()%></p>

           <img src="<%= reader.GetValue(2).ToString() %>" class="img" alt="">

       </article>
     <% } reader.Close(); %>
```

But I read somewhere that the code must be separated and it should be written in .aspx.cs file. What's the way to do this ? Assigning id's to the h and p tags and then assigning them values like this :

```
while (reader.Read())
    {
        h.InnerText = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
        p.InnerText = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
    }
```

But this does not solve the problem , because the posts will not be displayed in a loop i.e. 3 times.

I want to know a most suitable solution , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code you can modify as you wish

Code behind

```
// Here's your object that you'll create a list of
   private class Products
   {
      public string ProductName { get; set; }
      public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
      public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
   }

// Here you pass in the List of Products
   private void BindItemsInCart(List<Products> ListOfSelectedProducts)
   {   
    // The the LIST as the DataSource
      this.rptItemsInCart.DataSource = ListOfSelectedProducts;

    // Then bind the repeater
    // The public properties become the columns of your repeater
     this.rptItemsInCart.DataBind();
   }
```

Aspx code

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rptItemsInCart" runat="server">
      <HeaderTemplate>
      <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Product Name</th>
          <th>Product Description</th>
          <th>Product Price</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
       <td><%# Eval("ProductName") %></td>
       <td><%# Eval("ProductDescription")%></td>
       <td><%# Eval("ProductPrice")%></td>
     </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
  </tbody>
  </table>
 </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Accept answer if you satisfied with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using web forms, that would be easiest to solve using a `Repeater` control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx